# Is it possible not to render the header line in a primefaces datatable?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

We are looking for a way not to render the header of a datatable, but just the content. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this workaround/hack in one of my projects:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{myBean.myValue}" 
             var="item"
             ...>
  <p:column rendered="#{!empty item }">
    ..
  </p:column>
  ..
</p:dataTable>
```

I remember some issues with cell borders. But you should give it a try.